# Mysql create view error 1052

Tags: mysql, view, syntax-error

Hello stackoverflow people

I have a 2 tables that shares the same attributes, but in different categories. I am trying to list items ONLY with the attribute "Rending":

```
CREATE VIEW rending AS SELECT ranged_weapons.Name_, ranged_weapons.Dam, ranged_weapons.Dam_Type,
melee_weapons.Name_, melee_weapons.Dam, melee_weapons.Dam_Type
FROM ranged_weapons, melee_weapons 
WHERE Dam_Type = 'Rending';
```

but when i run it, i get:

```
Error Code: 1052. Column 'Dam_Type' in where clause is ambiguous
```

What am i doing wrong?

table information

```
  CREATE TABLE Ranged_weapons (
  Name_             varchar (40) NOT NULL,
  Class             varchar (40),
  Type_             varchar (40),
  Range_            varchar (40),
  RoF               varchar (40),
  Dam               varchar (40),
  Dam_Type          varchar (10),
  Pen               integer     ,
  Clip              integer     ,
  Rld               varchar (10),
  PRIMARY KEY (Name_),
  FOREIGN KEY (Name_) REFERENCES Items(Name_) ON DELETE CASCADE );


  CREATE TABLE Melee_weapons (
  Name_             varchar (40) NOT NULL,
  Type_             varchar (40),
  Dam               varchar (40),
  Dam_Type          varchar (40),
  Pen               integer     ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Name_),
  FOREIGN KEY (Name_) REFERENCES Items(Name_) ON DELETE CASCADE );
```

Comment: You have a column calles `Dam_Type` in both tables and MySQL doesn't know which one to use.

Comment: Please post the structures of those two tables. Right now, you have an implicit join with no joining condition, which means you'll get a cartesian product as the result. That isn't likely to be what you want, and both tables have a column `Dam_Type`.

Comment: Doing `SELECT *` in a join query (really anywhere in production code) is not good practice. Be explicit about the columns you need, especially since you have collisions between names.

Answer (score 1):

Thats says it all meaning the column is present in both the tables and you need to explicitly mention which table column you are referring to something as

```
CREATE VIEW rending AS SELECT *
FROM ranged_weapons, melee_weapons 
WHERE ranged_weapons.Dam_Type = 'Rending';
```

UPDATE : From the given table structures using the above code will show duplicate column name error since lot of column name is same across the tables.

The best thing is to select the columns explicitly for the view using JOIN or if needed to select the same column from the other table then using different alias names. Here is an example of how we can select and create the view using JOIN

```
CREATE VIEW rending AS 
SELECT rw.Name_,rw.Class,rw.Type_,rw.Range_,
rw.RoF,rw.Dam,rw.Dam_Type,rw.Pen ,rw.Clip,rw.Rld
FROM ranged_weapons rw
JOIN melee_weapons mw on mw.Name_ = rw.Name_
WHERE rw.Dam_Type = 'Rending';
```

If you want to select same columns for the view from different tables this how you can use alias

```
CREATE VIEW rending AS 
SELECT rw.Name_,rw.Class,rw.Type_,rw.Range_,
rw.RoF,rw.Dam,rw.Dam_Type,rw.Pen ,rw.Clip,rw.Rld,
mw.Name_ as mw_Name
FROM ranged_weapons rw
JOIN melee_weapons mw on mw.Name_ = rw.Name_
WHERE rw.Dam_Type = 'Rending';
```

Here `mw.Name_ as mw_Name` will refer to the column from melee_weapons and you can specify other column names this way if its needed for the view.

Comment: when i try to see the view nothing is displayed, all fields are empty

Comment: hmm could u please please provide some sample data , I suppose its not getting the matching data while joining the tables.

Answer (score 0):

DAM_TYPE is present in both tables that's why where clause unable to recognize it...

You must write table_name with DAM_TYPE in where clause..

Thanks